# Getting the ID of a lookup column?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, sharepoint-on-prem, ajax

I have a list which has a lookup column in it. "Subcats" has a lookup to "Cats". If I do an ajax call like this

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Subcats')/items?$select=Title,Category/Title&$expand=Category/Title",
```

I can get the Title from Cats but I can't get the ID.

```
var theCategoryTitle = data.d.results[result].Category.Title;
                  //var theCategoryId = data.d.results[result].Category.Id;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to REST API request to:

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Subcats')/items?$select=Title,Category/Id,Category/Title&$expand=Category`

This tells the REST API to get the Id and Title field values from the Category lookup field. If the Category list also had a Description field, you could get its value as well by changing the REST API request to:

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Subcats')/items?$select=Title,Category/Id,Category/Title,Category/Description&$expand=Category`

Finally, if you just wanted the Id of the lookup field (and not the Title or Description), you can get it without the use of `$expand`. Just append `Id` to the internal name for the lookup field.

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Subcats')/items?$select=Title,CategoryId`

Comment: You are a star Rob. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help